# Who will get the money at the end of GTA5 and how much?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In the ending of gta 5 if i kill trevor how much money does franklin and micheal get? And if i kill micheal who will not get the money that were supposed to be given in one of the characters because at the ending if you kill micheal one of the characters is not gonna get the money that they are supposed to get because lester gave it to micheals family so who is the character that didnt get the money that were supposed to be given to them is it trevor or franklin. And the deathwish ending will the all 3 characters get full 20 million or they have to share it someone pls explain im confused

Comment: someone pls use proper punctuation im confused